# Missing gcda file for C++ file in mixed C/C++ program, gcno generared for all sources

Tags: c++, g++, gcov

I have a program which include C and C++ code. It compiles fine and gcno files for all source files are generated. But when I execute code the gcda for most importnat object file is missing. The object is created and methods executed (I rund debug) but still gcda not generated.
I added _gcov_flush() into to object method which is called, still all other source files get gcda but not the object one.
What is possibly wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you lay out in detail what's the error you're getting? It's not clear from the text you posted.

Comment: There is no error to be preceise. My application have several source files, all with extension .cpp and compiled with g++ but only few of them include actual classes definition and impementation. The main object (class) is in separate file and constructor and some methods called from program main() function. During compilation *.gnco files are generated for all source files, but during execution the *.gcda for all but two. I am missing .gcda file to the main processing class which is the most interesting for me. So there is no error but lack of output in terms of .gcda file.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed Makefile and seems like calling gcov_flush finially helped. I am getting all gdca files but really not sure why did not got before.

Comment: Is `gcov_flush` a target in your `Makefile`? Is so, what does it do? Clear the output folder?